# attempting to return a multiple group by object

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

Was hoping for some help with Nested group by in linq where I am trying to go down three levels.

Basically the path would go down **Business** to **BusUnit** to **Level1**

So under Business there are various BusUnits and under BusUnits there are various level1 values

I want to return this as a Json object.

As I have it at the moment I got down to BusUnits

as follow

```
var queryNestedData = (from r in DataItems
                      group r by r.Business into businesses
                      from businessUnits in
                       (from r in businesses
                        group r by r.Businessunit)
                        group businessUnits by businesses.Key).Select(tg =>
                        new
                        {
                           Business = tg.Key,
                           BusinessUnits = tg.Select(tv => new { BusinessUnit = tv.Key })
                   });
```

How could I get to Level1 so as to return the values as well?

Comment: you tried `joins` in `LINQ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify related objects to include in the query results. Exact snippet depends from LINQ provider you are using. For Entity Framework it will be:

```
... from r in DataItems.Include(di => di.Business.Businessunit.Level1) ...
```